# Fragments display getting reset

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have setup a list of fragments using `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` on MainActivity as such

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Fragment1.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment2.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment3.OnFragmentInteractionListener, Fragment4.OnFragmentInteractionListener
, Fragment5.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapater(getSupportFragmentManager(), getApplicationContext()));

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#51ffff"));

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#ced21f"));
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#51ffff"));
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tabLayout.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }


    private class CustomAdapater extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String fragments[] = {"Control", "Connection", "Log", "Others", "Others2"};

        public CustomAdapater(FragmentManager supportFragmentManager, Context applicationContext) {
            super(supportFragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return new Fragment1();
                case 1:
                    return new Fragment3();
                case 2:
                    return new Fragment2();
                case 3:
                    return new Fragment4();
                case 4:
                    return new Fragment5();
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return fragments.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return fragments[position];
        }
    }
}
```

Somehow when I transit from Fragment1 to Fragment3 and back to Fragment1, the views on Fragment1 gets reset to original state(Like it was just created).

This only happens if I transit 2 fragment away from the current Fragment. For example 2->4 or 3->1. 
Everything is fine if the transition is next to each other, for example 2->3 or 1->2.

This is my first android app so do pardon me.

It seems like it is creating a new fragment instead loading of existing ones

Comment: As per my knowledge on fragments, In the viewpager view is load first and second at a time. and fragment state page adapter have to maintain the state reference. I mean if you goes second one 3 rd page is load like forward behaviour. That is the default behaviour of the viewpager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fragment get destroyed due to the fact that by default `viewpager` retain only one fragment at a time while moving around so you can simply use

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(no_of_fragment_to_retain);`

or

`viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);` // in your case

so when you come back from 4->1  or 3->1 you will get the previous stored state of your fragment. [link to docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#getOffscreenPageLimit())

Answer (score 0):

First :

viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomAdapater(getSupportFragmentManager(),   getBaseContext()));

Now see : in get Item method of View pager evrytime when you go to new tab a new instance of fragment is created So the previous view is lost . You should retain state in your fragment class. 
 or a simple solution is use FragmentstatepagerAdapter   instead of FragmentPagerAdapter in your Adapter class.
Let me know if it helps