# How to hold original fragment's contents, while go other fragment and come back to original fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

**MainActivity CODE:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnColorButtonListener {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    @Override

    public void onColorClick(int color) {

        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (color) {

            case 0:

                fragment = new RedFragment();

                break;

            case 1:

                fragment = new BlueFragment();

                break;

        }

         getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()

                .replace(R.id.fragment_ex, fragment).commit();

    }

}
```

**RedFragment CODE:**

```
public class RedFragment extends Fragment implements FlowerAdapter.FlowerClickListener {



    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeContainer_red;

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private RestManager mRestManager;

    private FlowerAdapter mFlowerAdapter;



    @Nullable

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_red, null);

        swipeContainer_red = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipeContainer_red);

        swipeContainer_red.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {

            @Override

            public void onRefresh() {

                mRestManager = new RestManager();

                Call<List<Flower>> listCall = mRestManager.getmFlowerApiService(getActivity()).getAllFlowers();

                listCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<Flower>>() {

                    @Override

                    public void onResponse(Call<List<Flower>> call, Response<List<Flower>> response) {

                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                            mFlowerAdapter.clear();

                            List<Flower> flowerList = response.body();

                            for(int i =0; i<flowerList.size(); i++) {

                                Flower flower = flowerList.get(i);

                                mFlowerAdapter.addFlower(flower);

                            }

                            swipeContainer_red.setRefreshing(false);

                        }

                    }

                    @Override

                    public void onFailure(Call<List<Flower>> call, Throwable t) {

                    }

                });



            }

        });

        configViews(view);



        return view;

    }



    private void configViews(View view) {

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.rv_flower_red);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mRecyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool());

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 3));

        mFlowerAdapter = new FlowerAdapter(this);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFlowerAdapter);

    }

    @Override

    public void onClick(int position) {

    }

}
```

When I read RedFragment's contents, I go to blue fragment and came back to RedFragment, RedFragment lost every contents that was on RedFragment before.

I want RedFragment will not be changed anything while i trip another Fragment.

**Question**

How can i make RedFragment set unchanged while i see other fragments things?

**Edit//RowFragment.java**

```
public class RowFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private OnColorButtonListener onColorButtonListener;
    public RowFragment() {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        onColorButtonListener = (OnColorButtonListener) context;
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_row, container, false);
        view.findViewById(R.id.v_red).setOnClickListener(this);
        view.findViewById(R.id.v_blue).setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.v_red:
                onColorButtonListener.onColorClick(0);
                break;

            case R.id.v_blue:
                onColorButtonListener.onColorClick(1);
                break;
        }
```

**My modified CODE: MainActivity's onColorClick method**

```
@Override
public void onColorClick(int color) {

    Fragment frag = null;
    switch (color) {
        case 0:
            frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("red");
            if(frag==null){
                frag=new RedFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_ex, frag, "red").commit();
            }
            break;
        case 1:
            frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("blue");
            if(frag==null){
                frag=new BlueFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_ex, frag, "blue").commit();
            }
            break;
    }
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag).commit();

    }
```

But that code has problem, when first click, it works well, but second click on the same color, it doesn't work anymore. What should i do to solve it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39543988/fragments-display-getting-reset read this , will solve your issue

Comment: You can use fragment Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of newFragment everytime try

```
Fragment frag=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(TAG);
if(frag==null){
 frag=new Fragment();
}
```

and while adding fragment specify a tag so that later you can comeback and revisit.

Also you can make use of `setRetainInstance` method and in `onCreate` set things back.

Comment: Sorry, I'm too newbie to apply your nice answer. How to get TAG? or How and Where to set TAG? Would you let me know more hint?

Comment: When you are adding fragment pass TAG also in replace method. Assume you have 3 Fragments and for 1st one tag is "Frag_1" and for 2nd "Frag_2" and so on. Use the same TAGs while finding the fragment too.

Comment: please Would you check my code(My modified CODE: ) depending on your teaching? Sorry for bothering you

Comment: Yes now it is right, if you want to set everything back to what is was, use setRetainInstance and in onCreate set things back, just follow some online tutorial for this, it is really easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was very helpful.